# Carbon "Hour can not be higher than 12"

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have in my app this date from frontend:

> '13-07-2017 14:00'

And I would test with:

```
try{
   Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date);

}catch (\Exception $err){
    return false;
}
```

Why it return always this error?

> InvalidArgumentException : Hour can not be higher than 12
>
> in Carbon.php (line 582)
> at Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:i', '13-07-2017 14:13')

So I use CAPITAL H , but my exception is throwed with 'h'

Answer (score 9):

So the problem here is that you use lower-case `h`. You pasted in your code `H:i` but from exception it's clear you use `h:i` instead.

Comment: He told you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti  You should use capital `H`. So you need to use `d-m-Y H:i` and not `d-m-Y h:i`

Comment: I USE capital! 
in my code I have : Carbon::createFromFormat("d-m-Y H:i", $date); with "H"

Comment: @LorenzoBerti Your error message states otherwise. "at Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y **h**:i', '13-07-2017 14:13')"

Comment: yes, but IT is my problem.
Even I use Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date); I don't understand why my exception use 'h'

Comment: Could be a variety of things - opcode caching, you didn't save your changes properly, there's more than one of these calls in your code, etc. Try editing the file directly on the server with `nano` and restart the webserver process.

Comment: I'm not sure what more we can do for you, then. The error shows a `h` is being seen by PHP/Carbon. I remain inclined to blame something like caching or editing the file wrong, because the alternative is a massive bizarre bug that'd be affecting millions of websites.

Comment: Thankyou ceejayoz, I Still try, however before down vote should make sure that the error exists, do not do it immediately...however thankyou

Comment: My guess would be is that you have that `try catch` somewhere else (maybe you put it in multiple places when testing it?), like your Controller, that is getting executed before this one.

Comment: Hello Taylor.. thank you, no I believe it is something like cache how @ceejayoz, now is ok, after many attemps, It work.... -.-"
However thank you!